# How to fix the crash in CFNotificationCenterAddObserver for NSWorkspaceDidActivateApplicationNotification?

Tags: c++, objective-c, qt, nsnotificationcenter, core-foundation

Not very much accustom to Objective C, hence trying to observe `NSWorkspaceDidActivateApplicationNotification` event in C++ code with `CFNotificationCenterAddObserver()` method.

```
#include<CoreFoundation/CFNotificationCenter.h>
#include<iostream>
#include<QGuiApplication>

void Callback (CFNotificationCenterRef center, void* observer, CFNotificationName name,
               const void* object,
               CFDictionaryRef userInfo)
{
  std::cout << "Hello World\n";
  //NSLog(@"New application: %@", [[name userInfo] objectForKey:NSWorkspaceApplicationKey]);
}

int main (int argc, char** argv)
{
  QGuiApplication application(argc, argv);

  std::cout << "Add observer\n";
  CFNotificationCenterAddObserver(CFNotificationCenterGetDistributedCenter(), nullptr, Callback,
                                  CFStringRef("NSWorkspaceDidActivateApplicationNotification"), nullptr,
                                  CFNotificationSuspensionBehaviorDeliverImmediately);
  std::cout << "Added ...\n";
  return application.exec();
}
```

However it results in below crash. If I try to run in debug mode, then it sometimes shows the below crash or sometimes get stuck in that function itself.

```
Add observer
2021-12-03 21:44:24.527086+0530 Test[17288:982994] -[__NSTaggedDate length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x100007c65
2021-12-03 21:44:24.527916+0530 Test[17288:982994] [General] An uncaught exception was raised
2021-12-03 21:44:24.527943+0530 Test[17288:982994] [General] -[__NSTaggedDate length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x100007c65
2021-12-03 21:44:24.528044+0530 Test[17288:982994] [General] (
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff35570035 __exceptionPreprocess + 256
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff5fc80a17 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff355e9fce -[NSObject(NSObject) __retain_OA] + 0
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff35511e9f ___forwarding___ + 1485
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff35511848 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff355aca4c __CFXNotificationRegisterObserver + 588
    6   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff3548a037 CFNotificationCenterAddObserver + 204
    7   Test                                0x00000001000066a1 main + 129
    8   libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff614503d5 start + 1
)
2021-12-03 21:44:24.528241+0530 Test[17288:982994] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSTaggedDate length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x100007c65'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff35570035 __exceptionPreprocess + 256
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff5fc80a17 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff355e9fce -[NSObject(NSObject) __retain_OA] + 0
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff35511e9f ___forwarding___ + 1485
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff35511848 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff355aca4c __CFXNotificationRegisterObserver + 588
    6   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff3548a037 CFNotificationCenterAddObserver + 204
    7   Test                                0x00000001000066a1 main + 129
    8   libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff614503d5 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

How to fix this?

Comment: The error means that at some point you think that you are using a `NSString` object, and call `length` (internally it's calling it, hidden Apple's SDK code) method on it. But in fact it's a `NSDate` (or as internal method says `NSTaggedDate`) object, which doesn't know the `length` method and crash.

Comment: @Larme, so what should be done to fix this error. Mind posting an answer?

Comment: `NSWorkspace` has its own [notificationCenter](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsworkspace/1525071-notificationcenter?language=objc).

Answer (score 1):

Use [CFSTR](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corefoundation/cfstr) macro to create a CFStringRef from a constant C string like so:

```
CFSTR("NSWorkspaceDidActivateApplicationNotification")
```

[NSWorkspaceDidActivateApplicationNotification docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsworkspacedidactivateapplicationnotification?language=objc%5D) says that you have to use [NSWorkspace.notificationCenter](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsworkspace/1525071-notificationcenter?language=objc) to receive it, CFNotificationCenterGetDistributedCenter won't work.

Comment: This only fixes the crash. However, still the `Callback()` is not invoked. Anything is still missed?

Comment: Updated the answer. I recommend to rename your file to .mm, and use Objective-C AppKit APIs instead of CoreFoundation C APIs. It is possible to combine C++ and Objective-C in one .mm file.